# Написать треугольник Серпинского методом хаоса

Tags: java

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main extends JFrame {


        static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
        static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    public Main() {
        setName("TicTacToe Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        Graphics g = m.getGraphics();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        g.drawLine(50, 450, 450, 450);
        g.drawLine(50, 450, 250, 50);
        g.drawLine(450, 450, 250, 50);
        int X=scanner.nextInt();
        int Y=scanner.nextInt();

        //A(50;450)
        //B(450;450)
        //C(250;50)

        for (int i = 2; i < 10001; i++){
            {int XS[]=new int[10001];
                int YS[]=new int[10001];
                Color OColor = g.getColor();

                Color NColor = new Color(255, 17, 7);
                g.setColor(NColor);
                g.drawLine(X,Y,X,Y);
                g.setColor(OColor);
                XS[1]=X;
                YS[1]=Y;
                int F = (int) ( Math.random() * 3);
        if (F==0){

            Color oldColor = g.getColor();

            Color newColor = new Color(255, 17, 7);

            g.setColor(newColor);

            XS[i]=(XS[i-1]+50)/2;
            YS[i]=(YS[i-1]+450)/2;
            g.drawLine(XS[i],YS[i],XS[i],YS[i]);

            g.setColor(oldColor);


        }
else{
            if (F==1){
                Color oldColor = g.getColor();

                Color newColor = new Color(255, 17, 7);

                g.setColor(newColor);

                XS[i]=(XS[i-1]+450)/2;
                YS[i]=(YS[i-1]+450)/2;
                g.drawLine(XS[i],YS[i],XS[i],YS[i]);
                g.setColor(oldColor);

                }
                else{
           //f=2


                XS[i]=(XS[i-1]+250)/2;
                YS[i]=(YS[i-1]+50)/2;
                Color oldColor = g.getColor();

                Color newColor = new Color(255, 17, 7);

                g.setColor(newColor);
                g.drawLine(XS[i],YS[i],XS[i],YS[i]);
                g.setColor(oldColor);

               }}}

        }

            }

    }
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос?

Comment: вопрос в том,почему точки не расставляются по заданному уравнению

Comment: опишите проблему непосредственно в теле вопроса (комментарии читают не все)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявленные внутри цикла массивы создаются при каждой итерации.
Вынеси

```
int XS[] = new int[10001];
int YS[] = new int[10001];
XS[1] = X;
YS[1] = Y;
```

за цикл

Comment: понял,спасибо огромное!